# Ajax Post to Laravel - CSRF Token Mismatch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to post data to Laravel backend with ajax, however I am getting 'CSRF token mismatch' error.

First, I've placed token in html (in body but outside its form because it's not the whole form, its only 2 elements to be posted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in 'document ready', I try to post the data with ajax.

```
data["_token"] = jQuery('#token').val();  

// Also tried this:
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('#token').val()
       }
})

console.log(data) // returns the array with _token: "esOKmY8Tpr4UvhTYMhWcWui0rpvYEjJ3es7ggics"

jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/my-route',
     data: data,
     success: function() {
          console.log("A");
     }
});
```

The data which I want to post are little chunk of a bigger form, and with using this approach, I can autocomplete form. The little chunk of html inputs are not inside any other sub-form. Maybe this can be the case?

```
- Form:
- A: bla // to be posted
- B: hello  // to be posted
- C: smt else // no post
```

but getting the values are working okay

Route:

`Route::post('/my-route', 'AdminController@theFunction')->middleware('admin');`

---

**Edit**: I changed `<input>` to `<meta>` tag

Comment: can you show us your route?

Comment: The issue looks like Origin Policy is wrong. Laravel CSRF should work out of the box without any tricks, under the normal circumstances.

Comment: Is the admin middleware doing a redirection?

Comment: I eventually cancelled the csrf for admin page.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684928/how-to-automatically-add-x-csrf-token-with-jquery-ajax-request-in-laravel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem 
try to put include CSRF tag in your `meta` like so

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and read it in your ajax code like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

**Last Update**

Please modify your url variable like so :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/my-route'+'?_token=' + '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    data: data,
    success: function() {
         console.log("A");
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you said. It's csrf token mismatch error again. I logged `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` and it successfully logs the token but Token Mismatch Error persists. Unfortunately, this is not the answer :/

Comment: Why don't you try to exclude this route from your Middleware ?

Comment: Try to add this to your ajax request  beforeSend: function(request) {
    return request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
  },

Comment: Can you add it in answer part above please? I didn't get how to implement it here

Comment: I am sorry I've modified it please take a look

Comment: Still getting the Token Mismatch Error :/

Comment: Please check the last update I've tried it right now and I believe the problem is because we should connect the url with _token

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
    $.ajax({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    url: 'save_search',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
    alert( data );
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue with my Laravel 8 where I noticed that the token was being sent in the URL through my AJAX request and the URL was correct.

However, despite this, I was still receiving an error. Upon further investigation, I realized that I had changed the value of `'same_site'` in my `session.php` file to `none`.

After changing it back to `'same_site' => "lax"`, I was able to resolve the issue.