# Cannot delete a row in Datatables after making it a delete request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables, laravel-9

I'm using DataTables in Laravel, and I want to delete a row from the database. It used to work when I did it as a get request in the route, but since I changed it to the delete request and put the csrf and method under the form, it stopped working. I receive - `Data Not Deleted` error. What can be a reason of that happening? Button that I receive from the index controller:

```
$button = '   <button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-fw  fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>';
```

HTML form that appears when a delete button is clicked:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="post" id="sample_form" class="form-horizontal">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Confirmation</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 align="center" style="margin:0;">Are you sure you want to remove this data?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="btn btn-danger">OK</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
        var employee_id;

        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
            employee_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
        });

        $('#ok_button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"/admin/employees/destroy/"+employee_id,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#ok_button').text('Deleting...');
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#employee_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    alert('Data Deleted');
                    }, 2000);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#employee_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        alert('Data Not Deleted');
                        }, 2000);
                },
            })
        });
    });
```

Route:

```
Route::delete('/admin/employees/destroy/{id}', [EmployeeController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Controller function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $data = Employee::findOrFail($id);
    $data->delete();
}
```

Comment: What’s the response you get in your browsers dev tools? Or how do you debug the response from any API call?

Comment: @dbf I receive this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Answer (score 1):

In your route you are using delete method, but in ajax call you have not mentioned the method, so the error is 405 method not allowed,

Try adding `type: delete` in ajax. something like this:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url:"/admin/employees/destroy/"+employee_id,
```

Comment: I did it before and it's still not working, only thing that is changing is the error in the console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)`

Comment: This issue is not related to 405 method. I guess, you have not included your csrf token in request header,  
check this convertation, it may help you. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539377/ajax-post-to-laravel-csrf-token-mismatch

Comment: indeed I had to put csrf inside the meta and declare it at the beginning of the script, now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I had to put csrf inside the meta:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And use this at the beginning of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```